# elsarticle - same author, same year - show year twice

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, elsarticle

By running this:

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{mieghem10assortativity,
    Month = {Nov},
    Numpages = {11},
    Publisher = {American Physical Society},
    author = {Van Mieghem, P. and Ge, X. and Schumm, P. and Trajanovski, S. and Wang, H.},
    title = {Spectral graph analysis of modularity and assortativity},
    journal = {Physical Review E},
    volume = {82},
    number = {5},
    pages = {056-113},
    year = {2010},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.82.056113},
}

@article{mieghem20assortativity,
Month = {Nov},
Numpages = {11},
Publisher = {American Physical Society},
author = {Van Mieghem, P. and Ge, X. and Schumm, P. and Trajanovski, S. and Wang, H.},
title = {Other title},
journal = {Physical Review E},
volume = {82},
number = {5},
pages = {056-113},
year = {2010},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.82.056113},
}
 \end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

blah. \cite{mieghem20assortativity,mieghem10assortativity} says
blah blah

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I get as output this:

blah. (Van Mieghem et al., 2010a,b) says blah blah

The question is how could I get

blah. (Van Mieghem et al., 2010a, 2010b) says blah blah

instead? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you decribe is not directly related to the `elsarticle` document class. Instead, it's caused by the fact that the `natbib` citation management package, which is loaded automatically by the `elsarticle` document class, compresses citation call-outs if the cited entries share the same authors *and* publication years. (Aside: The `natbib` package notes that `\citet` (or `\cite`) shouldn't be used with multiple arguments *unless* all arguments have the same set of authors.)

Rather than conduct a major hacking tour into the innards of the `natbib` package (not recommended!), you may want to pursue a less ambitious solution, i.e., one which uses `natbib`'s `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` macros to achieve an equivalent-looking solution. Of course, the `\specialcite` macro defined below should *never* be employed if the entries don't share the exact same authors and publication years.

[image]

That said, I really can't find anything objectionable about `\citet` and `\citep` perform compression of the citation call-outs of entries with the same authors and years.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{aa:2010a,
   author = "Anne Author",
   title  = "First Thoughts",
   year   = 2010,
}
@misc{aa:2010b,
   author = "Anne Author",
   title  = "Second Thoughts",
   year   = 2010,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\newcommand\specialcite[2]{\citeauthor{#1}\ (\citeyear{#1}, \citeyear{#2})}

\begin{document}
\citet{aa:2010a,aa:2010b}

\specialcite{aa:2010a}{aa:2010b}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```